# How can I step through a Perl program using Padre?

Tags: perl, debugging, padre

How can I step through a Perl program using Padre?

After much effort I installed CPAN Module Padre-1.00 on my home computer, which uses Windows 64bit and version 5.24.1 of Strawberry.

I also installed Padre's dependencies "Wx" and "Alien::wxWidgets", but all I can do with Padre at the moment is edit and save a Perl program, and run a Perl program from start to finish.

I see no icons for doing the normal debug activities, such as step into the next line, execute a function, and step out of a function

Can anyone help? There is a Padre web page saying you can use a Tools->Advanced option to get some additional icons on the toolbar but it doesn't work. Nor does there seem to be any key-binding for debug commands.

When I click the Padre’s "Bug" button – which supposedly puts Padre into a line-by-line debug mode – a DOS window titled "padre.exe -d  " appears, and within the DOS it says "Press any key to continue".

I have seen internet comments that Padre has bugs and has not been changed in a year.

Can anyone help?. Have you found a way to run a Perl program in Padre line-by-line?

Comment: [Padre](https://metacpan.org/pod/Padre) hasn't had a release in over 3 years.

Comment: Have you read [the docunentation](http://padre.perlide.org/features/perl5-debugger.html)?

Comment: Per the discussion on [Perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1184153), I believe you're better off trying a different IDE.

Comment: Padre seems to be a dead project. Time spent learning how to use it is probably wasted. Take a look at [Atom](https://atom.io/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite simple.  You can launch debugger by clicking on one of the top menus:

[image]

Now, in the right panel there will be step to next and step over buttons:

[image]